# Insert negative ASCII character in python string

Tags: python, string

In C, I can do that: `printf("%c%c",-108,109);`. But how to do it in Python?

```
args[2]='Test%c%cFile'% (-108,-109)
OverflowError: unsigned byte integer is less than minimum
```

Comment: Are you just trying to replicate a thing that C allows, or do you have an actual reason you would want to do this?

Comment: @user2357112 actual reason...You know Chinese Character is negative ASCII characters..

Comment: @Sayakiss: ...no they're not. What the heck? [This is ASCII.](http://www.asciitable.com/) You've probably been using weird, nonstandard terminal control characters or something.

Comment: Such blatant misunderstanding of the basics makes me wonder how the rest of their "internationalized" application works...

Comment: What does it print in C? Linux? Windows?

Comment: There are no Chinese characters in ASCII, which is strictly a 7-bit character set. It looks like you're trying to construct a UCS-2 or UTF-16 representation of the code point U+9493, which is in the range of CJK Ideographs.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it seems you want to put some non-ASCII characters into a string. Hacks involving negative integers are not necessary in Python, which has perfectly good Unicode strings for holding any character you could dream of. Use a code chart (like [this one](http://unicode-table.com/en/)) to find the code points for your characters, then insert them into your string using the `\uxxxx` syntax.

**Edit**: You seem to be after `U+9493` `CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-9493`, which can be inserted into a string using

```
str = u"\u9493"
```

(Thanks @KeithThompson!)

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that you have been relying on non standard behavior in your C code (one of the language lawyers can butt in and tell you if it's truly undefined or not).

You need to look into how to properly support non ASCII, multibyte character sets in python rather than just trying to duplicate your incorrect C code.

There are plenty of resources that will help with correct "i18n" of an app.